# React Swiper slideChange ，Go to the last page after data change

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

```
  initSwiper = (index) => {
    const swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiperCarousel", {
      initialSlide: index || 0,
      // loop: true,
      // spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        disabledClass: 'my-button-disabled',
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination-carousel',
      },
      observer: true, 
      observeParents: true, 
      preloadImages: false,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      lazy: true,
      watchSlidesVisibility: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
      speed: 0  
    });

    swiper.on("slideChange",async (e)=>{
      const {photos, photosPageInfo} = this.state
      if ( e.activeIndex === photos.length - 1 && photosPageInfo && photosPageInfo.hasNext) {
        this.POST_DATA.pageInfo.num++;
        await this._getDataForSwiper();
        swiper.update()
      }
    });

  }
```

If I have 10 pieces of data on one page, and there are 20 pieces in total after getting the second page, I expect to continue to play manually from 11 pieces, but in fact, after getting the second page data, it will automatically broadcast to the 20th piece

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUT56.jpg)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think slideChange event listener should update like this,

```
swiper.on("slideChange", async (e) => {
  const { photos, photosPageInfo } = this.state;
  const lastIndex = photos.length - 1;
  const activeIndex = swiper.activeIndex;

  if (activeIndex === lastIndex && photosPageInfo && photosPageInfo.hasNext) {
    // Load more data
    this.POST_DATA.pageInfo.num++;
    await this._getDataForSwiper();
    swiper.update();

    // Update activeIndex to account for new data
    const newLastIndex = photos.length - 1;
    const newActiveIndex = activeIndex - lastIndex + newLastIndex;

    // Set initialSlide to the last slide index before new data was added
    swiper.params.initialSlide = newLastIndex;
    swiper.slideTo(newActiveIndex, 0, false);
  } else if (activeIndex >= lastIndex) {
    // Disable autoplay and allow manual navigation
    swiper.autoplay.stop();
    swiper.allowSlidePrev = true;
    swiper.allowSlideNext = true;
  }
});
```

Hope this one help you.

Comment: thx, I tried your code, but it didn't work, I tried to adjust the pagesize to 3, every time swiper.on("slideChange") prints the last index of the latest page

Comment: Just updated the solution, can you try it again?

Comment: didn't work, this is my console output of activeIndex,After turning to the second page, it is like an automatic continuous broadcast, always requesting the next page by itself

activeIndex 1
activeIndex 2
activeIndex 5
activeIndex 8
activeIndex 11
activeIndex 14
activeIndex 17